# Problems using Cupertino when publishing to PlayStore and AppStore

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-store, cupertino-widgets, material-widget

I am building an app that would like to publish to the Google Play Store and AppStore. Hence my question, what problems await me when I use Cupertino date picker, for example. By problems, I don't mean user problems, but rather license, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Cupertino date picker and other Cupertino components in apps that are published on the Google Play Store. The Cupertino date picker is a user interface component that is part of the Flutter framework, which is an open-source project released under the BSD license. This means that you are free to use the Cupertino date picker in your app without worrying about any licensing issues.